# window click event vs a lot of buttons click event

Tags: javascript, algorithm, memory-efficient

I'm making an online store, and there will be a lot of "add to cart" buttons. When one gets clicked, a function will fire.

Which is more efficient, to make one `window click` event, then check if the button got clicked, and fire the function. Or should each button have it's `click` event?

Comment: "efficient" in which way?

Comment: @Dekel I guess if it's regular practice, or performance wise?

Comment: Logically it makes sense for each button to have its own click event handler. Any "performance gain" you'd get by tying all the buttons to the same event is going to be so small (microseconds, at best) as to be irrelevant, and will just make your code more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

From an Object-Oriented perspective, it would seem more reasonable to hook the button click event, because the button as an entity should encapsulate the logic relevant to it.

Then, for instance, if there are multiple types of buttons with slightly different characteristics, there will be a clear separation of logic, instead of it all remaining concentrated in a single monolithic piece of code.

Comment: How does it related to object-oriented perspective?